# Angular - reusing code (service or controller)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller, code-reuse

I'm using Angular to develop commenting functionality for a web app.
Currently there are two sections in the application were a user can comment:

- Category
- Product

About 90% of the commenting functionality is the same for both sections and as such I would like to make this reusable - i.e write some service or controller that I can reference/use as a base.

So far, my research seems to point to using a factory service but unfortunately this doesn't seem to work (I've spent the whole day running through various tutorials).

It is quite possible that I am over thinking this and making it far too complicated but I honestly don't know which way to turn anymore.

---

Herewith a quick and dirty overview of what I have so far:

1. HTML view for the category
2. Controller for the category (receives data from service and posts data to service in order to bind data to model)
3. Service for the category (retrieve and stores all the necessary
   data)

   The product uses the same logic and a lot of the code in the service and controller will be duplicated.
   I've merged the two services into one service successfully but I'm having trouble doing the same for the controller.

Do I:

1. Write a base controller that will communicate with the above mentioned service and that will hookup with the two existing controllers

   OR
2. Write a factory/provider service that hooks up to the two existing controllers as well as the above mentioned service.

Comment: Personally I would consider starting as directive , using one of the controllers that is working. Then determine what parts are different so you can define them as attributes to pass into directive scope. Services can be injected into directive at any time. Several things you would probably need to pass in right away would be `parent item`  and  `type`. The latter would be used for most of your conditional logic I suspect

Comment: Factory providers are the way to go for common functionality. You said you tried and it didn't work. What specifically didn't work? Show us your problem code and let us help you with that. BTW you can't inject `$scope` in factory providers.

Comment: I followed @S.Simpson's advice and now I can "access" the necessary methods in the shared factory. This seems to be working.
My only problem now is that I get a "Cannot read property 'then' of undefined" error.

In layman's terms, this is what is happening:
The controller calls a function in the shared service. The shared service in turn calls a function in the specific service (i.e. category or product). The latter passes a promise.  I suspect I have to return a promise in the share service as well?

Answer (score 0):

If you go the route of using a factory, you could put all the common functionality into its return object and reference that from your controllers.

**Factory**

```
angular.module('myModule').factory('CommonFunctions', function(){
  return {
    foo : foo,
    bar : bar
  }

  function foo(){ 
    console.log('foo'); 
  };
  function bar (){ 
    console.log('bar'); 
  };
}
```

**Controller**

```
 angular.module('myModule')
        .controller('myController', ['CommonFunctions', function(CommonFunctions) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.foo = CommonFunctions.foo();
    vm.bar = CommonFunctions.bar();
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help - that go me going in the right direction. Now I get a "Cannot read property 'then' of undefined" error. See my comment above for more details.

Comment: Since you are working with a promise you can do 2 things. You can make the thing getting updated after the promise resolves an object and return the object that will be updated to the controller. Since javascript passes objects by reference when the object on the service updates so will the one on the controller.   The other way would be to return the promise to the controller and do resolution there but typically you want to have your controllers doing just enough logic to handle what is going on in their respective view.

Answer (score 0):

angular's separation of service types ie:

- for specific values

  - constant
  - value
  - (constant for specific values needed before other  services are created)
- for functions

  - factory
  - service
  - provider
  - (provider for specific instances when you need a services before other services are created, usually taking advantage of constants)

allow the ability to share data and ways to process that data between controllers and or directives, anything that can be a `value` can also be a `constant`, the only difference there being where they can be injected. Similarly any `service` can be rewritten to a `factory` or a `provider`, it is more your specific use case / what your more comfortable writing that would determine which to use, but really the best way to think about it is if you have a value that needs to be shared but is not needed inside `angular.module.config` then use `value`, otherwise use `constant`, now if you have a single function that you want to share, (maybe it processes that value in some way or maybe it just does something else) you should write it as a factory, then when you have a few of those factory's that deal with either that value, or anything else, you can combine them into a `service` or configure and combine them using a provider. here is a simple example (note i am using the recommended syntax for writing angular services):

```
'use strict';
var app = angular.module('test.app',[]);

app.constant('configureableValue',{defaultValue:55});

app.value('editableValue',{defaultValue:100,editedValue:null});

app.provider('configureValue',configureValueProvider);
configureValueProvider.$inject - ['configureableValue'];
function configureValueProvider(configureableValue){
    var defaultVal = configureableValue.defaultValue,
        originalVal = defaultVal;
    return {
        getValue:getValue,
        setValue:setValue,
        resetValue:resetValue,
        '$get':providerFunc
    };
    function getValue(){
        return defaultVal;
    }
    function setValue(val){
        defaultVal = val;
    }
    function providerFunc(){
        return {
            get:function(){ return getValue(); },
            reset:function(){ resetValue(); }
        };
    }
    function resetValue(){
        defaultVal = originalVal
    }
}
// this factory is an example of a single function service, this should almost always be defined as a factory
app.factory('getEditableValue',getEditableValue);
getEditableValue.$inject = ['editableValue'];
function getEditableValue(editableValue){
    return function(){
        return editableValue.editedValue ? editableValue.editedValue : editableValue.defaultValue;
    };
}
// same with this one
app.factory('setEditableValue',setEditableValue);
setEditableValue.$inject = ['editableValue'];
function setEditableValue(editableValue){
    return function(val){
        editableValue.editedValue = val;
    }
}
// now this is an example of a service service collecting the factorys for an object with all the related behavior we need
app.service('editableService',editableService);
editableService.$inject = ['getEditableValue','setEditableValue'];
function editableService(getEditableValue,setEditableValue){
    var self = this;
    self.setVal = setEditableValue;
    self.getVal = getEditableValue;
}
app.config(appConfig);
appConfig.$inject = ['configureValueProvider'];
function appConfig(configureValueProvider){
    configureValueProvider.setValue('i changed '+ configureValueProvider.getValue() +' to this!!!!');
}

app.run(appRun);
appRun.$inject = ['configureValue','editableService'];
function appRun(configureValue,editableService){
    console.log('before editing: ',editableService.getVal());
    editableService.setVal('changed!!!');
    console.log('after editing: ',editableService.getVal());
    console.log('we changed this in the config func: ',configureValue.get());
    configureValue.reset();
    console.log('and now its back to the original value: ',configureValue.get());
}
```

i know thats a lot for a simple example, but there are a lot of features provided by angular, and many ways to use them, hopefully this helps.